# Displaying Django DB values on index.html original path

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a DB hat hs some values in it. I want to display these values on my `index.html`. i want to display them on the standard html path `path('', views.index, name = "index"),`

I currently displaying them at `path('this_is_the_path/', my_db_class.as_view()),`

The problem is that i am pulling the values from a class. and i can't figure out how to set the class to the original index.html path.

***Models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class Database(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

***Views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Database

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,"index.html",{})

class my_db_class(ListView):
    model = Database
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

***URLS.PY***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import my_db_class


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
    path('this_is_the_path/', my_db_class.as_view()),
]
```

***HTML.PY***

```
<ul>
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <li> {{ post.text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So my problem is that the above code will only show my DB values at the `this_is_the_path` path, but i want to show it at the `''` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modify your index function like this.
views.py

```
def index(request):
    object_list = Database.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'object_list':object_list})
```